# Safari: Fixed background + transition

Tags: macos, webkit, css-transitions, safari

[Example site](http://codepen.io/mastastealth/full/icaBx)

I have a site divided into your usual vertical sections. Header and footer both contain backgrounds with background-attachment: fixed. I have a slide-out nav, which you can see is activated on the first link. Everything works dandy except...

Issue:
Safari 6 (I'm not sure about 5.1, but it seems to be on Mac as my Windows Safari doesn't have the issue) has a nasty flicker upon animation. This can be resolved with the usual -webkit-backface hack HOWEVER upon using this, a new problem arises. The fixed background images start behaving very badly, and if you scroll/resize the browser enough, the images get distorted or content overlays improperly. Is there an alternative method I can use for this technique, or an actual fix?

HTML

```
<section>Hi <a href="#">CLICKME</a></section>
<section>hi</section>
<section>hi</section>
<section>hi</section>
<footer><p>I am some text</p></footer>
<aside class="menu">
  I'm a menu.
</aside>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: #222;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

body.bump {
  transform: translate(-258px, 0);
}

section {
  background: #CBA;
  color: white;
  line-height: 450px;
  font-size: 32px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 1;
}
section:nth-child(2) {
  background: #FAFAFA;
}
section:nth-child(3) {
  background: #CCC;
}
section:nth-child(4) {
  background: #ABC;
}

section:first-child {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/1600/500) center top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
@media all and (min-width: 73.75em) {
  section:first-child {
    background-size: cover;
  }
}

footer {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/1400/500) center top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  height: 500px;
}
@media all and (min-width: 73.75em) {
  footer {
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
footer p {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 200px;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

aside.menu {
  background: #222;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: left;
  transform: translate(516px, 0);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 258px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.bump aside.menu {
  transform: translate(258px, 0);
}
```

JS (using Jquery)

```
$('section a').click( function(e) {
  $('body').toggleClass('bump');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround, by applying the fixed background to the body, wrapping everything in body in another div (animating that instead, so it wasn't affecting the body background) and the footer stayed the same, since having scrolled that far there is no way to pop the sidebar out anyway (so no animation flicker to worry about).